# GCMTaskService - One Off Task setPersisted, setRequiredNetwork(Task.NETWORK_STATE_CONNECTED) and setRequiresCharging Android

Tags: android, gcmtaskservice

I want to ask few questions related to GCM One off Task in Android. Read many docs but unsure of the following:

1. Does One off task supports setPersisted? If yes, what is the default value.
2. What is the exact meaning of NETWORK STATE CONNECTED ? Does it consider only manual toggling of mobile data or also detect connection from limited connection to strong connection ?
3. What is the default of setRequiresCharging for One Off task?

Please do not mix One off task and Periodic Task while replying.

Comment: Good question, but no documentation available from google